# How to find the biggest values of (three values) without using looping them? [Python]

Tags: python

i'm new to programming and this has got me stumbling and i was thinking of doing something like this but i can't got further

```
num1 = int(input('What is the first number?:'))
num2 = int(input('What is the second number?:'))
num3 = int(input('What is the third number?:'))
```

[[After this my mind is thinking of elif statements and using [and,or]]

Comment: `max(num1, num2, num3)`

Comment: Thank you i will look into what the max syntax is all about.

Comment: @coldspeed a bit pedantic, but `max([num1, num2, num3])` is the correct syntax since the `max` function requires an iterable for the first argument.

Comment: @Joel It works as is. Because max takes variable arguments.

Comment: A little googling would surely solve your problem.

Comment: Well i did google and they kept prompting me with while loops . the question was to solve it without while loops.

Thanks for the community and I understood the syntax clearly . after @coldspeed answered

Comment: @coldspeed good catch, I must be thinking of some other function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add all of your `variables` to a `list` and then you can use the `max` function like so `max(lista)`

```
num1 = int(input('What is the first number?: '))
num2 = int(input('What is the second number?: '))
num3 = int(input('What is the third number?: '))

lista = [num1, num2, num3]

biggest = max(lista)

print(f"{biggest} is the largest value.")
```

> ```
> (xenial)vash@localhost:~/python/stack_overflow$ python3.7 max.py
> What is the first number?: 10
> What is the second number?: 3
> What is the third number?: 8
> 10 is the largest value.
> ```

Just for a little bonus, didn't include handling `TypeErrors` but want to give you some ideas where you can go with this little project:

```
while True:

    numbers = int(input("How many numbers would you like to enter: "))

    values = []

    for i in range(numbers):
        if i == numbers - 1:
            values.append(int(input(f"Enter 1 number: ")))
        else:
            values.append(int(input(f"Enter {numbers - i} numbers: ")))

    print(f"\nThe largest number entered was {max(values)}")
```

> ```
> (xenial)vash@localhost:~/python/stack_overflow$ python3.7 max.py
> How many numbers would you like to enter: 5
> Enter 5 numbers: 10
> Enter 4 numbers: 8
> Enter 3 numbers: 29
> Enter 2 numbers: 13
> Enter 1 number: 22
>
> The largest number entered was 29
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Python's max(list) does the job for you.

If you wish to create a function that accepts arbitrary amount of inputs, you can create a function like this.

```
def my_function(*args):
    return max(args)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
num1=int(input('What is the first number?:'))
num2=int(input('What is the second number?:'))
num3=int(input('What is the third number?:'))
if(num1>num2 and num1>num2):
    print(num2, 'is the largest value')
elif(num2>num1 and num2>num3):
    print(num2, 'is the largest value')
else:
    print(num3, 'isenter code here the largest value')
```

Comment: Please add more details, possibly an explanation of your answer so its easy for others to understand. Appreciate it!

Comment: Thanks for good advice, i will try to explain it. It was very simple program i made it as it is simple that's why i didn't explain it.